# Touch not working in mainscene

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am unable to figure out the why. could someone please say where the bug is?

Xcode 6.1.1
Cocos2d 3.1.0

I used a break point to see if the touch method is getting called or not.
Its never being called when i test and touch in device.

I used this line blow in main method

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

also super on enter is called below main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make certain your object instance has a content size set in onEnter. Touch may be enabled, but with (0,0) content size, they are not being dispatched. Also, you must have a touchBegan method in your code. The following lines are pretty much 'boilerplate' for my UI bearing classes:

```
- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

- (void)onEnter {
    [super onEnter];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    // replace following two lines by whatever works for your 
    // specifics, but make certain that you have them and that
    // the object's geometry falls in the display screen.
    // setPositionInPointsW is in my own CCNode category, not in cocos2d
    [self setPositionInPointsW:self.viewPort.origin];    
    self.contentSizeInPoints = self.viewPort.size;
}
```